# parsing dictionaries into csv file

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

What are the best ways to filter out specific keys from these dictionaries then write into csv file?

These data are stored in a text file and have multiple of these. This is just a portion of data.

```
{u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 3, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-30T17:50:00.533Z', u'dataFrame': u'AB3hqqqpVVVOAAA=', u'id': 1480528200533L, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': -8.5, u'rssi': -116, u'port': 5}
{u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 5, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-30T17:50:35.613Z', u'dataFrame': u'AB3hqqqpVVVOAAA=', u'id': 1480528235613L, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': -5.8, u'rssi': -119, u'port': 5}
{u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 7, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-30T17:51:50.609Z', u'dataFrame': u'AB7hqqqpVVVOAAA=', u'id': 1480528310609L, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': -8.8, u'rssi': -120, u'port': 5}
{u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 9, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-30T17:53:23.504Z', u'dataFrame': u'AB7hqqqpVVVOAAA=', u'id': 1480528403504L, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': -9.2, u'rssi': -116, u'port': 5}
{u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 13, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-30T17:55:25.060Z', u'dataFrame': u'AB7iqqqpVVVOAAA=', u'id': 1480528525060L, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': -8.5, u'rssi': -111, u'port': 5}
{u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 15, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-30T17:56:48.140Z', u'dataFrame': u'AB7iqqqpVVVOAAA=', u'id': 1480528608140L, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': -8.2, u'rssi': -110, u'port': 5}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail. Are you simply trying to filter a certain key from every dict? Are you trying to filter based on value?

Comment: I would like to have data sets in csv for all time and data values from this file.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [
{u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 3, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-30T17:50:00.533Z', u'dataFrame': u'AB3hqqqpVVVOAAA=', u'id': 1480528200533, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': -8.5, u'rssi': -116, u'port': 5},
{u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 5, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-30T17:50:35.613Z', u'dataFrame': u'AB3hqqqpVVVOAAA=', u'id': 1480528235613, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': -5.8, u'rssi': -119, u'port': 5},
{u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 7, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-30T17:51:50.609Z', u'dataFrame': u'AB7hqqqpVVVOAAA=', u'id': 1480528310609, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': -8.8, u'rssi': -120, u'port': 5},
{u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 9, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-30T17:53:23.504Z', u'dataFrame': u'AB7hqqqpVVVOAAA=', u'id': 1480528403504, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': -9.2, u'rssi': -116, u'port': 5},
{u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 13, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-30T17:55:25.060Z', u'dataFrame': u'AB7iqqqpVVVOAAA=', u'id': 1480528525060, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': -8.5, u'rssi': -111, u'port': 5},
{u'decrypted': True, u'fcnt': 15, u'timestamp': u'2016-11-30T17:56:48.140Z', u'dataFrame': u'AB7iqqqpVVVOAAA=', u'id': 1480528608140, u'sf_used': 10, u'snr': -8.2, u'rssi': -110, u'port': 5}
]
filt = ['dataFrame', 'timestamp']
with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    for row in data:
        values = [str(row[i]) for i in filt]
        print(', '.join(values), file=outfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

`DictWriter` seems more elegant for me in this case

```
import ast
import csv

with open('input.txt', 'r') as in_f, open('data.csv', 'w') as out_f:
    data = in_f.readlines()

    # Take specific fields and ignore others
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_f, fieldnames=['id', 'dataFrames', 'timestamp'], extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()  # For writing header

    for row in data:
        dict_row = ast.literal_eval(row)  # because row has a dict string
        writer.writerow(dict_row)
```

Comment: Oh! I thought you have a list of dictionaries. My bad. I missed the part where you said it's input file. I'll update my answer.

Comment: If you feel this answer is acceptable as the solution, you can accept this answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv.writer`

```
with open('data.csv', 'w+') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
       if key in ["timestamp", "dataFrame"]:
           writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: @James updated.  Haven't tested, but I think it works.

Comment: sorry, i should have mentioned that all those data are contained in a file.. can i still use iteritems()?